# How to update recycler view using ListAdapter?

Tags: java, android

I'm currently using RecyclerView ListAdapter.

I would like to know what is the equivalent of **notifyDataSetChanged** or how to update the whole list after adding a value/record?

I am using this method currently, but it's not updating if it's not refreshed.

### Initializing the record

```
mList = new ArrayList<>();

mList.add(new ModelClass();

mAdapter.submitList(mList);
```

### Some code after creating a new record

```
mAdapter.submitList(null)

mAdapter.submitList(modifiedList)
```

I'm thinking of going back to `RecyclerView.Adapter<VH>` and `notifyDataSetChanged()` so that my problems are solved. What do you think?

Comment: `RecyclerView.Adapter` does what it says.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve same.
**First way:**

```html
adapter.notifyItemInserted(itemIndex);
```

Here,  **itemIndex**  is the position in the array where you want to add a new element. This will not refresh the entire list on the recycler view. 
But will just add this element to that position.

**Second Way:**

```html
arrayData.addAll(insertIndex, items);
adapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(itemIndex, items.size());
```

**Third Way:**

```html
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

So, like I have mentioned above there are multiple way of updating a list in recycler view

Comment: thanks! after I submiList, i've just added notifyDataSetChanged